# Swift get UnsafePointer of variable

Tags: swift, swift2

I can't realize how to create a pointer of an existing variable in swift.
Something like `int pointer = &variable` in C++.

I created this by myself actually:

```
    var s = "Hello"
    print(s)

    func pointer(p: UnsafeMutablePointer<String>) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<String> {
        return p
    }

    let p = pointer(&s)
    p.memory = "Bye"

    print(s)
```

So it prints "Hello", then "Bye".

But I could't believe there is no standard function for this.